# how to interpret the sharp decline in loss in seq2seq models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions, lstm, autoencoders

I have a seq2seq model. I have applied this data over `20_newsgroup` data set.

My problem is that I face with `exploding gradient` so when I print the weight they are `nan`.

Then I decide to finish the training early before it gets nan.

this is the plotting of loss of training vs validation.
I have three questions here:

1. I have a sharp decline in the loss, can it be a sign it got stuck in local minima? if not what could be a good justification of this behaviour?
2. based on the diagram what would you suggest to experience a more stable model?
3. which optimizer doing better?

with `sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.)` and batch_size = 64

[image]

In case you think the structure of model can be useful to drive conclusion:

This is the structure of my data:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LEN, VOCAB_SIZE), name="input")
encoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(LATENT_SIZE, kernel_initializer="glorot_normal",), merge_mode="sum", name="encoder_lstm")(inputs)
# encoded = Lambda(score_cooccurance,  name='modified_layer')(encoded)
decoded = RepeatVector(SEQUENCE_LEN, name="repeater")(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(VOCAB_SIZE, return_sequences=True)(decoded)
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
# sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=1.0)
sgd = SGD(lr=0.04, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=1.0, nesterov=True)
# sgd = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
autoencoder.summary()
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='checkpoint/50/{epoch}.hdf5')
history = autoencoder.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=num_train_steps, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

and this is the way I have prepared data:

```
sent_wids = np.zeros((len(parsed_sentences),SEQUENCE_LEN),'int32')
sample_seq_weights = np.zeros((len(parsed_sentences),SEQUENCE_LEN),'float')
for index_sentence in range(len(parsed_sentences)):
    temp_sentence = parsed_sentences[index_sentence]
    temp_words = nltk.word_tokenize(temp_sentence)
    for index_word in range(SEQUENCE_LEN):
        if index_word < sent_lens[index_sentence]:
            sent_wids[index_sentence,index_word] = lookup_word2id(temp_words[index_word])
        else:
            sent_wids[index_sentence, index_word] = lookup_word2id('PAD')

def sentence_generator(X, batch_size):
    while True:
        # loop once per epoch
        num_recs = X.shape[0]
        indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(num_recs))
        num_batches = num_recs // batch_size
        for bid in range(num_batches):
            sids = indices[bid * batch_size : (bid + 1) * batch_size]
            temp_sents = X[sids, :]
            Xbatch =to_categorical(temp_sents, num_classes=VOCAB_SIZE, dtype='int32')
            yield Xbatch, Xbatch
```

This is some statistics about my data (20_news_group data set):

```
number of sentences: 58280
distribution of sentence lengths (number of words)
min:1, max:141, mean:47.863, 25quart:32.000, med:50.000, 75quart:64.000
vocab size (full): 114490
```

I have also feed the model with paragraphs, and these paragraphs were prepared by concatenating 15 sentences together:

```
def readingfiles():
    paras = []
    splitLen = 15
    dirname = './Data/20news/'
    documents = getlistoffiles(dirname)
    for file in documents:
        with open(file, encoding='latin1') as f:
            input = f.read().split('\n')
            at = 1
            for lines in range(0, len(input), splitLen):
                # First, get the list slice
                outputData = input[lines:lines + splitLen]
                outputData = [x.replace('\n','').replace('\t','') for x in outputData if x]
                at += 1
                if len(outputData)>0:
                    paras.append(outputData)

    return paras
```

**Update1**

I find out why it faces exploding weight though I don't know how can I fix it!

So the problem was not related to data issue, as I checked it with amazon data set and the same thing happened(nan weights).

When I changed the `one_hot encoding` to embedding and use `mse` as a loss the model behaved well without facing `nan weights`.

So in summary, the same model with `one_hot encoding` and `categorical cross-entropy for loss` face with exploding weights.

The same model with `word embedding technique` and `mse loss` it behaves normally.

**Update 2**

So finally I have done this:

1. I tried the same model with also `categorical cross entropy` and `one hot encoding`.
   (Before going through that, I should mention that as you see in the code the `vocab_size` is set to `2000`, however, the whole `vocab_size` available is more than `100000`. So I had OOV problem).

So I decided to try with the same model and same `one-hot encoding` but with less data so that I am not forced to decrease `vocab_size`.

In this scenario (fewer data so I could have the whole data in my sentences, so not facing with OOV problem), the model behaved normally.

So, per my hardware limitations, I can not afford to have one_hot encoding with a large number of data which my system crashes.

**What I have done as the solution is,** I trained a word embedding with `embed_dime=2000` over my data set separately and then I exactly followed the approach proposed [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-Keras/blob/master/Chapter07/sent-thoughts-rnn.py). with this I can have the matrice with size `(latent_size, Embed_size)` in the encoder and embed_size is also `2000` which is not small.

Though I'm not sure if it is a stable approach or not, Or I could do anything else to get `one_hot encoding` works on my data?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I suppose your data is not well normalized. LSTM's standard activation is `tanh`, which will only result in numbers between -1 and 1. 
You should check the range of your input data and see 1 - if it's within the range of your activation function and 2 - if it's not within a very tiny range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LSTM uses Gated Recurrent Units (GRU), which is [known](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2017/readings/L15%20Exploding%20and%20Vanishing%20Gradients.pdf) to be sensitive to gradient vanishing or exploding. The usual solution is to introduce a gradient clipping mechanism.

Basically we merely rescale the gradients to prevent them from blowing up. The goal is to keep their norm at most a predefined threshold value.

In tensorflow, this is [straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498127/how-to-apply-gradient-clipping-in-tensorflow).

Actually I found a [blog post](https://blog.csdn.net/u010814042/article/details/76154391) (though in Chinese) that compares using gradient clipping (before and after) for a LSTM model. I post the figures here for conveniency.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for following my question:), So you mean that the sharp decline is because of the exploding gradient, Right? and I had tried `cliping before` but not getting much different result. The other problem here is that training line is above validation line. isnt it weird?

Comment: Do you think based on the statistic I provided, the way that I prepared data could be a reason? (joining 15 sentences to form a paragraph and then set the seq lenght to `60` which is around 75 percentile of the lenght of the sentences.

Comment: you could use a non-lstm model  to verify whether it is a data problem or model problem. I believe a linear classifier or DNN should be less prone to gradient explosion. If they works, you could eliminate the possibility of data problem.

Comment: Sure I will try the linear classifier, So one last question, among these which diagram sounds a little bit more reasonable?

Comment: I think there is a problem here, when I set the `vocab_size=2000`, and then I prepared the sequences and do pad sequences regardless of this `vocab_size`. Then what will happen in a sequences that has a word that is not part of the most common words(vocab_size=2000)?

Comment: All the diagrams look similar. They all seem to indicate your intuition about gradient explosion is correct. Regarding out-of-vocabulary (oov) word, you want to look at the documentation of your nltk tokenizer how they handle oov.

Comment: I will try all the things that you said then I will back with my result. Again Many thanks for putting time :)

Comment: could you please have a look at my updates? I followed the things that you mentioned and find the root cause of the nan weights in my case

Comment: Also, this code is exactly the code in the 7 chapter of deep learning with keras available here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-Keras/blob/master/Chapter07/sent-thoughts-rnn.py , which only the word representation changed from embedding to one hot encoding

Comment: I think I found the reason, and it is related to OOV problem. Im not sure which strategy should I take If I have to limit the number of vocab and at the same time keep all the sentences. that does not sound right!!! can you please share your idea with me:)

Comment: If you found the reason, can you update your question with more details (regarding oov). How does your current tokenizer handle oov words ? How/whether do you use oov bucket in the word embedding case? what about one-hot encoding?

Comment: I have just updated the question with the things I have done, Could you please have a look at the update 2 and if possible let me your idea?

Comment: I have seem people training embedding dimension from 100 up to 1000. Usually 200-512 is sufficient. I think your choice of using a word embedding is much better than hot encoding because that does use of the transfer learning knowledge in your pre-training process.

Comment: What about the stability of the model? because model won't be stable if I train embedding while training(as I have embedding in the target output and it keeps changing every time). I am worried this way could have any disadvantage that I'm not aware of!

Comment: this is the best practice. Use a large corpus for pre-training the embedding. then you can use a learning speed schedule to incrementally increase the learning speed (using for example 10% of the training data). You could also freeze your embedding in the first 10% of training steps. Then unfreeze it after the initial training steps.

Comment: In the approach that I'm following I keep the `training= False` for the embedding. Don't you think it would be better in this way as I'm only interested in the encoder part?

Comment: In my experience, usually keeping embedding with trainable=True helps improving the entire model quality. But if in your context, you are only interested in a particular encoder based on fixed word embedding, that seems a reasonable usage as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your experience with me, really appreciate it. and Sorry for mentioning you every time I face with a problem, I'm kind of new to LSTM networks and trying to increase my knowledge and get my project done asap:) (I will try both approaches)

Comment: np. happy that you are progressing.